# uipv6 on arm processor family

Tags: arm, ipv6, atmega

I need to port the u(read mu)ipv6 stack from atmega platform to the arm platfom, specificcally to STM32F103Rx so i need the libraries for this processor. But I have no idea where to find them. Could anyone please point me in the right direction??

Answer (score 0):

STM32 support in Contiki/uIPV6 is not present in the stable release (2.4), you need the upcoming 2.5 version. Here is release candidate 1:

http://www.sics.se/contiki/news/contiki-2.5-release-candidate-1-avaliable.html

http://sourceforge.net/projects/contiki/files/Contiki/Contiki%202.5-rc1/contiki-2.5.rc1.zip/download

Enjoy!